# MVC 3 application converting views to dll

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, razorgenerator

i am developing an application in mvc3 razor which will be deployed in multiple shared hosting accounts. I want to compile the application into dll as it did in asp.net aspx file, which said "This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!" How can this be achieved with razor views.

Comment: Views do not need to be compiled.

Comment: See the [razor generator project page](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/). there is a walk-through entitled "Usage in an MVC app" that may be helpful. (I also assume you're asking because other views have already been compiled?)

Comment: @BradChristie : I tried razor generator, but failed. It gives error cannot find views after generating dll. I don't know what i am doing wrong there.

Comment: @nitin update your question with what you've tried.